# Flask_PyMongo SSL Handshake Failed with certificate file provided, deploying on gcloud App Engine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, gcloud

My Name is Eitan and I'm new to google cloud and Flask_PyMongo. When I try deploying to the App Engine, I get an error saying: "pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed", even though I direct a local pem file to the tslCAFile property in the url.

I've tried alternate methods like certifi.where(), ssl=False, ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE, and directing a pem certificate to my local project, but I still kept getting the same error. Here is my code:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo, MongoClient
app = Flask(__name__)
# Note: The password isn't the problem, I just don't want to leak the actual password ofc
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb+srv://eitanbrochstein:password@cluster0.rhtkmvj.mongodb.net/Flask?authSource=admin&tlsCAFile=cacert.pem"
mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    # #create one
    print(mongo.db.users.insert_one({"user": "Username"}))
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 app:app

runtime_config:
    operating_system: "ubuntu22"
    runtime_version: "3.11"
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.1.3
Flask-PyMongo
certifi
dnspython
Werkzeug==2.2.2
gunicorn
```

Comment: Try changing your code to: `ca = certifi.where()` and `tlsCAFile=ca`

Comment: Thanks for the response @JohnHanley, sadly this didn't work for me, but thanks for trying to help!